# Some space showing � in the html page

Tags: html

In a html page, some space showing �. I am also using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the head, but not working. Here is an example:

```
Movie: Bombay Velvet
Singer:�Suman Sridhar
Music:�Mikey McCleary
Music Label: Fox Music
```

I am trying to figure out from yesterday, but couldn't. Please help, what might be causing this issue.

**Solved:** mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connect);

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Check encoding (utf-8) and filter and/or sanitize what is causing the output.

Comment: Check the file encoding and make sure it's utf8

Comment: try to open your file on notepad > save as > change the encoding to UTF > save (overwrite) and se if it works =]

Comment: Make sure you also have `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: Actually it is a php page, trying to pull all content from mysql saved in utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: I also tried saving the file in UTF in notepad and reupload. But not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @DilipKumar read the answers on the post linked above, that **will** solve your issue.

Comment: @Martin OK i will follow your link

Answer (score 0):

As your data comes from a Database and PHP. You can set connection enconding at startup.

If you are using Mysqli connection driver you can do this:

`mysqli_set_charset ( $mysql_connection , 'utf8' );`

or in OOP:

`$mysql_connection->set_charset('utf8');`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.set-charset.php

In another drivers you need to see similar function.

Comment: Sorry not working yet. May be some other problem here. I will go for the link provided by Martin

Comment: Charset problems is very anoing. You need to verify these things:

 - if your connection to database are responding in correct charset. 
 - if your files are saved in correct enconding (in Atom, this is showed at bottom bar)
 - if your http request in on correct encoding (this can be changed at runtime using:

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: yeah i tried checking it from the server side and yeah it is saved in UTF. And also i tried header in php, not working yet.